# How can I split an SQL query into parts, clean them and get the features between clauses using Python?

Tags: python, sql, strip

I have the following SQL query and want to break it into parts in order to get the features in the SELECT, FROM clauses and the WHERE conditions using Python.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.ra, p.dec, p.objid, p.run, p.rerun, p.camcol, p.field 
FROM photoobjall AS p 
WHERE (p.run=# AND p.camcol=#) AND p.field=# AND p.rerun<>#
```

I only want to get

```
select_features = [ra, dec, objid, run, rerun, camcol, field]
from_features = [photoobjall]
where_conditions = [(p.run=# and p.camcol=#) and p.field=# and p.rerun<>#]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python regex for parsing SQL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49321785/python-regex-for-parsing-sql-statement)

Comment: I have tried using regular expressions to split the queries like:: select_clause = re.search(r"(?<=select)(.*)(?=from)",s).group(0), from_clause = re.search(r"((?<=from)(.*)(?=(where|group by)))|((?<=from)(.*))",s).group(0), if a is not None:
   group_by_clause = re.search(r"(?<= group by)(.*)",s).group(0), if b is not None:
   where_clause = re.search(r"((?<=where)(.*)(?=(group by)))|((?<=where)(.*))",s).group(0)

Comment: I have also thought of spliting the query string into list elements, find the select, from, where and group by indices and then take the parts between them and split them accordingly which seems more efficient I but I don't know how to get there.